# How to create RasterStack with one layer for each year

Tags: r, r-raster, r-sf, rasterizing

I have an `sf` object that contains yearly observations of a variable for multiple units. I want to rasterize this so that there is one `RasterLayer` for each year from 1946-2005 (the start year for the observations differ). The data looks like this:

```
> head(data)
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 4 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 0.5 ymin: 26.63 xmax: 0.5 ymax: 26.63
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
# A tibble: 6 x 5
   id   year       var1        geometry
  <dbl> <int>     <dbl>       <POINT [°]>
1   615  1957         1        (0.5 26.63)
2   615  1958         1        (0.5 26.63)
3   615  1959         1        (0.5 26.63)
4   615  1960         1        (0.5 26.63)
5   615  1961         1        (0.5 26.63)
6   615  1962         1        (0.5 26.63)
```

Each `RasterLayer` should contain information of the absence or presence of `var1` for all geometry points.

I attempted with the following code, but this creates a two-layer `RasterBrick` instead of the 59-layer `RasterStack` that I want.

```
r <- raster::rasterize(data, raster, field = c("var1", "year"), fun = "first")
```

Comment: You could use a for loop to rasterize for each year and then stack the raster layers afterwards.

Comment: The function is not set up for that You could either loop, or change your points to a wide format where easy year is a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using a loop, takes some time to run it 40 000 locations but it works

```
setwd("E:/MA_2Try/annual_NDVI/average")
grids <- list.files("E:/MA_2Try/annual_NDVI/average" , pattern = "*.tif$",full.names=TRUE)
NDVI_stack=stack(grids)

#Add dates to stack layers
dt<-as.data.frame(
  as.Date(c('2002-01-01','2003-01-01','2004-01-01','2005-01-01','2006-01-01',
            '2007-01-01','2008-01-01','2009-01-01','2010-01-01','2011-01-01',
            '2012-01-01','2013-01-01','2014-01-01','2015-01-01','2016-01-01',
            '2017-01-01','2018-01-01','2019-01-01')))
years <- format(as.Date(dt[,1], format="%d/%m/%Y"),"%Y")
NDVI_stack <- setZ(NDVI_stack, years,"year")

#extract NDVI values
ex <- list()

for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  
  if (data$year[i] == 2009) {
    NDVI <- raster::extract(NDVI_stack[[8]], data[, 5:6])
  } 
  else if (data$year[i]==2010) {
    NDVI <- raster::extract(NDVI_stack[[9]], data[, 5:6])
  } 
  else if (data$year[i]==2011) {
    NDVI <- raster::extract(NDVI_stack[[10]], data[, 5:6])
  } 
  else if (data$year[i]==2012) {
    NDVI <- raster::extract(NDVI_stack[[11]], data[, 5:6])
  } 
  else if (data$year[i]==2013) {
    NDVI <- raster::extract(NDVI_stack[[12]], data[, 5:6])
  } 
  else if (data$year[i]==2014) {
    NDVI <- raster::extract(NDVI_stack[[13]], data[, 5:6])
  }  
  else if (data$year[i]==2015) {
    NDVI <- raster::extract(NDVI_stack[[14]], data[, 5:6])
  }
  else if (data$year[i]==2016) {
    NDVI <- raster::extract(NDVI_stack[[15]], data[, 5:6])
  }
  else if (data$year[i]==2017) {
    NDVI <- raster::extract(NDVI_stack[[16]], data[, 5:6])
  }
  else if (data$year[i]==2018) {
    NDVI <- raster::extract(NDVI_stack[[17]], data[, 5:6])
  }
  else if (data$year[i]==2019) {
    NDVI <- raster::extract(NDVI_stack[[18]], data[, 5:6])
  }
  else if (data$year[i]==2020) {
    NDVI <- raster::extract(NDVI_stack[[18]], data[, 5:6])
  }
  else if (data$year[i]==2021) {
    NDVI <- raster::extract(NDVI_stack[[18]], data[, 5:6])
  }
  ex[[i]] <- list(id=data$id[i], y=data$y_[i], NDVI= NDVI[i])
  
  progress(i, 41290)
  Sys.sleep(0.02)
  if (i == 41290) message("Done!")
  
}
output <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, ex)
setwd("E:/Masterthesis/wildcat_data/second_order/seasons")
write.csv(output,'extracted.NDVI.summer.csv')
```